# What is the probability that the sum of their squares is at least 0.8?

Tags: probability

Two real numbers are randomly chosen from the interval [0, 1]. What is the probability that the sum of
their squares is at least 0.8?

So for a circle it will be $r=\sqrt{.8}$

So
$ P[S]=1-P[S]$

$P\left[\overline{S}\right]=\frac{\pi \times \sqrt{0.8}^2}{4}=0.628$

Then $P[S]= 1-0.628=0.372$

Is this the correct way to go about this problem?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Change your first line to say $P[S]=1-P[\overline{S}]$.

Comment: And some of the $=$ to $\approx$.